# Magento 2 How to remove price filter from category if module is enable?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, price, layered-navigation, filter

I have one module is set up and it has configuration about enable/disable the module. **I have multiple stores too**. I want the functionality to disable or hide price filter from category page if the module is enabled or not.

**In my module, I have the function in helper which returns the value of module enabled or not.  It would depend on store view.**

**As the price attribute has global scope, So we can not directly use this:**

**Catalog->Attributes ->Manage Attributes -> Price -> Use In Layered Navigation -> "No".**

Now I want to disable the price filter from left/right navigation from the category page.

Is anyone have any an idea about it?

in `Helper\Data.php` I have content as below:

```
namespace Name\Module\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    const XML_CONFIG_ENABLE = "sectionid/groupid/fieldid";

    protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;      
    }

    public function getModuleStatus()
    {
        return  $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_CONFIG_ENABLE, \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you update your module code so that I can write a answer based on your module? Atleast the helper class.

Comment: in my module, I have system.xml file and Data.php it has a function which returns the value if the module enables then return 1 otherwise 0.

Comment: Can you update the whole helper file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the below code to your **di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList" type="Name\Module\Model\Layer\FilterableAttributeList" />
</config>
```

And create **FilterableAttributeList.php**
under

> app/code/Name/Module/Model/Layer/FilterableAttributeList.php

with following content:

```
<?php
namespace Name\Module\Model\Layer;

class FilterableAttributeList extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList
{
    protected $collectionFactory;
    protected $storeManager;
    protected $helper;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Name\Module\Helper $helper
    ) {
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->helper = $helper;
        parent::__construct($collectionFactory, $storeManager)
    }

    protected function _prepareAttributeCollection($collection)
    {
        $collection->addIsFilterableFilter();
        if($helper->getModuleStatus() == 1){
            $collection->removePriceFilter();
        }
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much @Sukumar Gorai its working fine.

Comment: Welcome. Happy Coding!